# Erro no Revolution Slider

Tags: html, wordpress, slider

Estou utilizando o plugin **Revolution Slider**, sempre usei ele e é a primeira vez que tenho problemas.
Quando eu adiciono texto no meu `Slider`, ele cancela a reprodução automática. Já tentei tirar as tags HTML e utilizar a paleta de configuração do plugin, mas, não adiantou. Quando eu tiro os textos, ele volta a funcionar normalmente, mas de nada adianta se não tiver texto.

O plugin está atualizado e todas as suas configurações estão corretas, alguém pode me ajudar?